# How to have dynamic columns (like for weeks w1, w2, w3...) to contain number value as score in Sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, power-automate

See attached spreadsheet screenshot.

How to incorporate dynamic / ever increasing columns with custom labels such as **W1, W2, W3** to contain number value (score 0-4). Presently I have spreadsheet to record score. How is it possible to achieve via SP list using *SP List *or* Powerapps*?

1. One way is I can have **Title** as text but how can I save week values? How will I increment column name at runtime?
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

No easy way using just SharePoint, except to prebuild all of the "W" columns. You could use unpivoted data (Title, Wnumber, value) in a SharePoint list and then use an embedded Power BI report to display the data.

The Power Apps solution would be similar to the Power BI.